# jquery UI problem sending string extracted from ui.item object

Tags: jquery-ui, variables, object

I have 2 sortable, connected lists with pics: Album and Favorites.
When I drag and item from Album -> Favorites I want to check if it's already in the Favorites list.

If it is, do NOT accept it (maybe disable sorting or something?)

If it is not, clone the item back to the original index in Albums (connected sortable lists do only move items, so this mimics copying)

I have a function that checks if the pics are in the Favorites list:

```
function isInFavorites(url) {
    return $(".favorites li img[src*='" + url + "']").length > 0;
}
```

This function works like expected...
However when I extract the scr attr with ui.item and pass the argument to this function I always get a true boolean??

```
var itemSrc = ui.item.find("img").attr("src");
if (isInFavorites(itemSrc)) { alert('item allready in favorites, do not accept'); } 
else { alert('OK, now clone back to album'); }
```

I have been banging my head way to long on this and would appreciate some help!
A JS Fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/tunafish/CTps3/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to process the logic but the order the events are firing is the source of your problem

```
function isInFavorites(url) {
    return $(".favorites li img[src*='" + url + "']").length > 0;
}
```

This event runs AFTER the item has been moved. if it is a duplicate you will have length 2, but you will always have length 1 because you just moved the item into the lower list.

quick fix is to test for `$(".favorites li img[src*='" + url + "']").length > 1`

Comment: That's it! You are right, after the 'receive' method, the item IS in the list. If I use the function with the 'start' method it works like expected. Thanks sooooo much Bobby!!!